# android.widget.Spinner.setAdapter(android.widget.SpinnerAdapter) on a null object reference

Tags: java, android-studio

> Error : java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual
>   method 'void
>   android.widget.Spinner.setAdapter(android.widget.SpinnerAdapter)' on a
>   null object reference

I tried to debug codes and arrayList has array data and codes to create arrayList works well.

```
ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
                            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonArray.getString(i));
                                arrayList.add(jsonObject.getString("title"));
                            }
                            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter3 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, arrayList) {
                                public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                                    View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

                                    return v;
                                }
                            };
                            spinner2.setAdapter(adapter3);
```

Comment: Is ```spinner2``` initialized ?

Comment: As @Agnaramon suggests - the error indicates that `spinner2` is not initialised.

Comment: spinner2 is initialized in onCreate before this code.

Comment: @MajidJalilian can we see initialization in ```onCreate``  and its declaration in layout xml file ?

Comment: thanks, I found my problem in onCreate I used "spinner2 = findView ..." but before this one time again I wrote "Spinner spinner2 = ..." I removed second part and problem solved after.